# React Material-Table - How can I add commas between cell that is rendered from fetched array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using Material Table for managing workstations. Some of the data I receive are arrays, they are automatically iterated and displayed in cell but without commas.

[Current behavior picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEi0x.png)

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VnM2.png)

I feel like overriding whole cell component is overkill and I would like to avoid modyfing fetched array. Is there is any way that I can modify that iteration done by Material Table at "MTableCell" component ? Or maybe there is some smarter way of doing this ?

Comment: Please provide your coding implementation

Comment: There it is https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-water-rv3b3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `attribs` is your data as array (as shown in the picture):

```
const attribs = ['ATTRIBUTE1', 'ATTRIBUTE2', 'ATTRIBUTE3'];
```

You can use `reduce` to convert that to a comma-separated string:

```
const separated = attribs.reduce((prev, current) => `${prev},${current}`);
```

And then feed that into the material table cell. You can check a simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-19c9z?file=/demo.js

Comment: Yeah, that was my first tought but i'm trying to avoid another itteration on this array since the cell component does it anyway

Comment: I don't think you can avoid that, because the cell component doesn't do what you need. Unless you create your own cell component and make the material table use that component instead.

Comment: Too bad :< But thanks anyway, i guess i ll stick to this one then